# Monitor directory using inotify_add_watch fails on read()

Tags: c, linux

Im trying to make inotify_add_watch() work on monitoring directory but read() fails and gives me errno 22. Ive tried an actual file not directory, is seems working on (IN_MODIFY) event.

```
#define FILE_DIR "/etc/folder"
#define FILENAME "/etc/folder/file"

include <stdio.h>
include <unistd.h>
include <sys/inotify.h>

struct inotify_event ev;
gint file_fd = -1;
gint file_wd = -1;
ssize_t readRet = -1;

void notify()
{
    file_fd = inotify_init();
    if (-1 == file_fd) {
        return;
    }

    file_wd = inotify_add_watch(file_fd, FILE_DIR, (IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE));
    if (-1 == file_wd) {
        return;
    }

    readRet = read(file_d, &ev, sizeof(ev));
    if (-1 == readRet) {
        printf("Error %d", errno);
    } else {
        print("Read ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: use `perror()` or `strerror()` to get a human-readable error message.

Comment: Error code 22 is EINVAL, which according to [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) means the buffer you're trying to read into isn't big enough to hold the event.

Comment: (you don't have space for a file name)

Comment: @Shawn You mean struct inotify_event can't be used on this case?